# Array randomization

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to return random value from an array and Java keeps giving me error. I'm using eclipse IDE.

I tried changing to String to Object

```
int rnd = new Random().nextInt(name.length);
return name[rnd];
```

I expect random value from this code.

Error I receive is

```
Error: Main method must return a value of type void in class Package.Learn01, please 
define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: *keeps giving me error*  - please share you stack trace

Comment: `void` means that nothing should be returned, maybe just try printing it?

Comment: syntax error... is SO suppose to be an interactive compiler?

Comment: how can I get stack trace on eclipse?

Comment: No need, this is a compile error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have is that you're trying to return something from a main method, which you can't do in Java; the main method has to have return type of void. Since the compiler is looking for a main method that's matching exactly what it expects a main method to look like, an error will occur if it doesn't.
I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by returning from main, anyways...